# Activate PHP OpenSSL module on Mac Yosemite

Tags: macos, mac, php, openssl

I've got a new MacBook Pro (with latest Yosemite) I'm setting up for web development. I am running PHPStorm as my IDE. PHPStorm cannot use its built-in `composer` functionality, saying it cannot connect to the packagist repo. It seems this is because the mac doesn't have PHP OpenSSL activated:

```
php -i | grep "SSL Version"
SSL Version => SecureTransport
```

Is there a way to install OpenSSL *without* building a whole new PHP with `brew` or `port`? I'm using VMs for most of my development now and I'm really trying to avoid customizing the new clean machine, instead messing with all my server stuff in the VM.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to phpstorm support this is a bug in their product. They pointed me to an unreleased beta and the functionality worked as designed.